# "Caractère" : est-ce que ça peut vouloir dire "personnage" / "personnalité" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je me demande si "caractères" ici ça va en parlant de chiens (j'avais marqué "personnages" mais on m'a conseillé de changer de mots) :

*Les refuges abritent les espèces d'animaux les plus diverses, de tous âges et de toutes tailles. Vous y trouverez certainement de nombreux **caractères** intéressants qui conviendront parfaitement à votre personnalité et à votre style de vie.*

Merci!

Answer (score 1):

Oui, "caractères" convient ici.

"Personnage" peut être employé pour désigner une personne et mettre l'accent sur sa personnalité ou sur un trait de caractère principal.
*C'est un personnage sinistre.* Ici, on désigne une personne et résume sa personnalité à son caractère sinistre.
Cet usage est réservé à des êtres humains, on ne désigne pas un animal de la sortie.

On peut en revanche tout à fait parler du "caractère" d'un animal pour désigner ses traits principaux : agressif, énergique, paresseux, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On peut parler du caractère ou de la personnalité d'un chien, mais *trouver de nombreux caractères intéressants* est plus problématique. *Personnages* ne se dit qu'en parlant d'êtres humains, de personnes comme la racine du mot l'indique.

Je te propose donc:

> Les refuges abritent les espèces d'animaux les plus diverses, de tous âges et de toutes tailles. Vous y trouverez certainement des animaux aux caractères variés et intéressants qui conviendront parfaitement à votre personnalité et à votre style de vie.

Comment: @20goto10 Merci ! Qu'est-ce que vous pensez de *individues* (suggéré par @LPC)?

Comment: Aucun francophone n'utiliserait *individu* dans cette phrase pour désigner des animaux. Le sens courant d'individu est *être humain*, *personne*.

Answer (score 1):

Un terme souvent employé pour parler d'animal de compagnie est "compagnon"

> Les refuges abritent les espèces d'animaux les plus diverses, de tous âges et de toutes tailles. Vous y trouverez certainement un compagnon au caractère intéressant qui conviendra parfaitement à votre personnalité et à votre style de vie.

Answer (score -1):

Je crois qu'il faut itérer le conseil qui vous a été donné : « caractère » n'est pas plus approprié que les choix précédents. C'est un terme qui ne s'utilise que pour les êtres humains. Un terme qui conviendra,  le mot "**individu**", ne sera pas nécessairement de votre gout, mais il est si général que l'on peut l'appliquer des grains de sables aux êtres humains en passant par les animaux.

Comment: ??, *Individu* pour un grain de sable. Ce sens a disparu depuis longtemps !

Comment: @jlliagre — TLFi : 1. Tout être concret, donné dans l'expérience, possédant une unité de caractères et formant un tout reconnaissable.   Dans l'usage général (et en philosophie) un individu est un objet de pensée appartenant à l'extériorité ou à nos représentations, déterminé et reconnaissable. Il porte un nom « commun » mais se distingue « matériellement » des autres individus portant le même nom.
LEGRAND 1972.—  C'est un terme aussi employé par certains mathématiciens pour parler d'un élément spécifique dans un ensemble. Pourquoi exclure des specimen de roche ou même des grains de sable ?

Comment: Parce que personne ne considère un gain de sable comme étant un *être*.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais quel est le critère ? TLFi : Un roman, un poème, un tableau, un morceau de musique sont des individus, c'est-à-dire des êtres où l'on ne peut distinguer l'expression de l'exprimé, dont le sens n'est accessible que par un contact direct et qui rayonnent leur signification sans quitter leur place temporelle et spatiale (MERLEAU-PONTY, Phénoménol. perception, 1945, p. 177)

Comment: 1. Merleau-Ponty parle de créations humaines, d’œuvres, pas de grains de sables. 2. Il peut se permettre des personnifications ou des métonymies, mais elle ne sont pas généralisables.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi alors utiliser ces personnifications dans une définition générale du terme ?

Comment: Les auteurs du TLFi s'attendaient probablement à ce que leurs lecteurs fassent preuve de *sens commun*.

Comment: @jlliagre Du bon sens, en somme…

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu entends pas *itérer*?

Comment: @jlliagre Ça ne se comprend pas comme « répéter » ? Je vais vérifier…

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai que c'est vieux: (TLFi) A. Vx. ,,Faire une seconde fois, une troisième fois, etc...`` (LITTRÉ). Synon. réitérer.

Comment: J'avais compris que tu voulais dire répéter, mais le fait est que tu ne répètes pas du tout ce qui a déjà été écrit puisque l'autre réponse dit que "caractère convient" et toi tu dis "caractère ne conviens pas plus que les choix précédents", ce qui signifie le contraire.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je fais référence aux conseils donné aux demandeur initial à qui il a été conseillé de changer de mot. Je voulais dire "répéter l'avis pour ce nouveau terme", mais bien sûr c'est un peu lapidaire.

Comment: Donc, tu ne vois pas de problème à dire qu'un grain de sable est un individu, mais parler du caractère d'un chien, pas question ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je vois l'idée insinuée, bien sûr. Je suis d'accord sur le fait qu'il existe une psychologie animale, que l'on puisse parler d'une certaine façon du "caractère" d'une bête, encore qu'il faudrait un mot propre au bêtes, mais je ne veux pas franchir le fossé et appeler une bête un caractère, mot qui a toujours été utilisé seulement pour les humains. Les animaux d'un côté, les humains de l'autre, et après ça on peut bien penser à instituer une charte du droit des gorilles…

Comment: TLFi: *Caractère: I.− Trait(s) distinctif(s) d'une **chose**. Le caractère spécifique, dominant d'une chose; dégager, souligner le caractère particulier d'une chose.*

Comment: Tu confonds peut-être avec l'anglais *character* (personnage) ?

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je ne conteste pas ça mais le passage de « caractère d'une chose » à « caractère étant un état d'être de la chose toute entière ». D'ailleurs, il me semble que « caractère », lorsqu'il désigne une personne entièrement, n'est employé qu'avec un qualificatif (un grand caractère, un caractère immonde, un noble caractère, …). Lorsque l'on dit « c'est un caractère » sans qualificatif on dit que la personne a un caractère spécial, en général pas facile.

Comment: @tamaz J'ai lu l'échange rapidement. Ça dépend du contexte, pas nécessairement de la sémantique à mon avis. Dans un documentaire animalier où l'on parle du comportement animal, je peux imaginer trouver _individu_ par rapport au reste du groupe. « Quelques individus se tiennent loin du groupe » ou je ne sais trop mais dans ta phrase le contexte est différent et la phrase devient vague avec _individus_ parce que je peux imaginer de manière loufoque qu'on parle des propriétaires ou des gens qui travaillent au refuge. Je n'ai pas pris le temps d'analyser la question mais j'ai pensé à _spécimens_.

Comment: @20goto10 j'aime bien spécimens ! *Exemplaire* en serait aussi un synonyme acceptable selon mes recherches

Comment: @Tamaz _Exemplaire_ ne fonctionnerait pas dans ta phrase à mon avis...

Comment: @20goto10ça marche, j'ai proposé *spécimens* au final. Merci bcp à tout le monde :)